# Soln to the "Found multiple CRI endpoints on the host" issue?

Tags: server, kubernetes

(Apologies if this is a dumb question...)

```
chuck@k8smaster:~$ sudo systemctl status crio
● crio.service - Container Runtime Interface for OCI (CRI-O)
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/crio.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: active (running) since Fri 2022-12-16 15:36:06 UTC; 28min ago
       Docs: https://github.com/cri-o/cri-o
   Main PID: 955 (crio)
      Tasks: 25
     Memory: 59.1M
        CPU: 563ms
     CGroup: /system.slice/crio.service
             └─955 /usr/bin/crio
chuck@k8smaster:~$ sudo kubeadm init --pod-network-cidr=192.168.2.0/16
Found multiple CRI endpoints on the host. Please define which one do you wish to use by setting the 'criSocket' field in the kubeadm configuration file: unix:///var/run/containerd/containerd.sock, unix:///var/run/crio/crio.sock
To see the stack trace of this error execute with --v=5 or higher
chuck@k8smaster:~$ sudo kubeadm init --pod-network-cidr=192.168.2.0/16 --v=5
Found multiple CRI endpoints on the host. Please define which one do you wish to use by setting the 'criSocket' field in the kubeadm configuration file: unix:///var/run/containerd/containerd.sock, unix:///var/run/crio/crio.sock
k8s.io/kubernetes/cmd/kubeadm/app/util/runtime.detectCRISocketImpl
    cmd/kubeadm/app/util/runtime/runtime.go:166
k8s.io/kubernetes/cmd/kubeadm/app/util/runtime.DetectCRISocket
    cmd/kubeadm/app/util/runtime/runtime.go:174
k8s.io/kubernetes/cmd/kubeadm/app/util/config.SetNodeRegistrationDynamicDefaults
    cmd/kubeadm/app/util/config/initconfiguration.go:112
k8s.io/kubernetes/cmd/kubeadm/app/util/config.SetInitDynamicDefaults
    cmd/kubeadm/app/util/config/initconfiguration.go:63
k8s.io/kubernetes/cmd/kubeadm/app/util/config.DefaultedInitConfiguration
    cmd/kubeadm/app/util/config/initconfiguration.go:242
k8s.io/kubernetes/cmd/kubeadm/app/util/config.LoadOrDefaultInitConfiguration
    cmd/kubeadm/app/util/config/initconfiguration.go:276
k8s.io/kubernetes/cmd/kubeadm/app/cmd.newInitData
    cmd/kubeadm/app/cmd/init.go:300
k8s.io/kubernetes/cmd/kubeadm/app/cmd.newCmdInit.func3
    cmd/kubeadm/app/cmd/init.go:153
k8s.io/kubernetes/cmd/kubeadm/app/cmd/phases/workflow.(*Runner).InitData
    cmd/kubeadm/app/cmd/phases/workflow/runner.go:183
k8s.io/kubernetes/cmd/kubeadm/app/cmd.newCmdInit.func1
    cmd/kubeadm/app/cmd/init.go:104
github.com/spf13/cobra.(*Command).execute
    vendor/github.com/spf13/cobra/command.go:916
github.com/spf13/cobra.(*Command).ExecuteC
    vendor/github.com/spf13/cobra/command.go:1040
github.com/spf13/cobra.(*Command).Execute
    vendor/github.com/spf13/cobra/command.go:968
k8s.io/kubernetes/cmd/kubeadm/app.Run
    cmd/kubeadm/app/kubeadm.go:50
main.main
    cmd/kubeadm/kubeadm.go:25
runtime.main
    /usr/local/go/src/runtime/proc.go:250
runtime.goexit
    /usr/local/go/src/runtime/asm_amd64.s:1594
chuck@k8smaster:~$ sudo kubeadm init --pod-network-cidr=192.168.2.0/16 --cri-socket=unix:///var/run/cri-dockerd.sock
[sudo] password for chuck: 
[init] Using Kubernetes version: v1.26.0
[preflight] Running pre-flight checks
error execution phase preflight: [preflight] Some fatal errors occurred:
    [ERROR CRI]: container runtime is not running: output: time="2022-12-16T16:25:36Z" level=fatal msg="unable to determine runtime API version: rpc error: code = Unavailable desc = connection error: desc = \"transport: Error while dialing dial unix /var/run/cri-dockerd.sock: connect: no such file or directory\""
, error: exit status 1
[preflight] If you know what you are doing, you can make a check non-fatal with `--ignore-preflight-errors=...`
To see the stack trace of this error execute with --v=5 or higher
chuck@k8smaster:~$ sudo kubeadm init --pod-network-cidr=192.168.2.0/16
Found multiple CRI endpoints on the host. Please define which one do you wish to use by setting the 'criSocket' field in the kubeadm configuration file: unix:///var/run/containerd/containerd.sock, unix:///var/run/crio/crio.sock
To see the stack trace of this error execute with --v=5 or higher
```

Comment: What's the question again?

Comment: How do I get past this error?

Answer (score 0):

This error indicate you have both installed containerd and CRI as a runtime but you can only use one. If you want to use CRI uninstall containerd

```
 apt-get purge containerd
```